# Error when running command inside variable with `if`

Tags: shell, variables, if-statement

We've got a script running the last 2 commands. But it's failing..

```
$ if [ -d / ]; then echo a; else echo b; fi
a
$ bash -c 'if [ -d / ]; then echo a; else echo b; fi'
a
$ A="bash -c 'if [ -d / ]; then echo a; else echo b; fi'"
$ $A
[: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''
[: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

I really wonder why? Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to SO. You need backticks `` or `$()` instead of double quotes for the last command line. try this: `A=$(bash -c 'if [ -d / ]; then echo a; else echo b; fi')`

Answer (score 0):

In your last command line, you have assigned a value to the variable `A`, but failed to evaluate it before calling `$A`. Instead, any of the following will work:

Define the variable and then evaluate it,

```
 ~]# A="bash -c 'if [ -d / ]; then echo a; else echo b; fi'"
 ~]# eval $A
```

OR evaluate it first and then `echo` it.

```
 ~]# A=$(bash -c 'if [ -d / ]; then echo a; else echo b; fi')
 ~]# echo $A
```

OR not personally preferred, you can also use this:

```
 ~]# A="eval bash -c 'if [ -d / ]; then echo a; else echo b; fi'"
 ~]# $A
```

All of the above will result in `a`.

Note: See why you shouldn't use the third option: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048

Answer (score 0):

Let's take a simpler example to explain:

```
$ A="bash -c 'echo hello'"
$ $A
hello': -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''
hello': -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

When executing `$A`,
the shell performs word splitting on the value of `$A`.
It finds these words:

- `bash`
- `-c`
- `'echo`
- `hello'`

You probably expected that `'echo hello'` would be evaluated to the value `echo hello` (without the single-quotes), but that is not the case.
It cannot happen.
When you set the value of `A` with `A="..."`,
any `'...'` embedded within the `"..."` are not evaluated,
so the literal `'` remain in place.
It would be dangerous to recursively evaluate string values like that.

So after the word splitting, what gets executed looks more like this:

```
bash -c "'echo" "hello'"
```

So then `bash` tries to execute the command `'echo`, and it fails,
because it doesn't find a matching `'`.

As for what is the `hello':` prefix of the error messages,
I believe this extract from `man bash` explains:

```
SYNOPSIS
       bash [options] [command_string | file]

...

       -c        If the -c option is present, then commands are read from  the
                 first non-option argument command_string.  If there are argu-
                 ments  after  the  command_string,  the  first  argument   is
                 assigned  to  $0  and any remaining arguments are assigned to
                 the positional parameters.  The assignment  to  $0  sets  the
                 name  of  the  shell, which is used in warning and error mes-
                 sages.
```

As another example, in the original code in the question,
the error messages were prefixed with `[:`, because after the word splitting of `"bash -c 'if [ -d / ]; then echo a; else echo b; fi'"`,
the next word after `'if` is `[`.

If you really want to do something like this, you could use an array instead:

```
A=(bash -c 'if [ -d / ]; then echo a; else echo b; fi')
"${A[@]}"
```

By writing this way, `A` will have 3 values:

- `bash`
- `-c`
- `if [ -d / ]; then echo a; else echo b; fi`

And these will be used as 3 words when executing,
producing the expected output `a`.